# Validating empty strings with Joi

Tags: javascript, forms, frontend, joi

When validating strings with Joi, with the following schema:

```
title: Joi.string().required(),
```

It's not validating empty strings like the following: `"   "`. I don't think it's correct to repeat `string().trim()` on every field. How can I validate empty strings? Shouldn't Joi handle this, according to the [docs](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.4.0#string)?

> Note that the empty string is not allowed by default and must be
> enabled with allow(''). Don't over think, just remember that the empty
> string is not a valid string by default. Also, don't ask to change it
> or argue why it doesn't make sense. This topic is closed.

Comment: `''` and `' '` are two different things, you need to trim in your case.
The quote `Don't over think, just remember that the empty string is not a valid string by default.` is referencing the behaviour you can see between `Boolean('')` and `Boolean(' ')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.regex()](https://github.com/sideway/joi/blob/master/API.md#objectregex) to validate your fields.

As an example, the following schema will validate any string that only contains spaces (at least one):

```
const schema = Joi.object({
    a: Joi.string().regex(/^\s+$/)
})

schema.validate({ a: ' ' }) // valid
schema.validate({ a: '     ' }) // valid
schema.validate({ a: '' }) // invalid, adding .allow('') will validate
schema.validate({ a: '1 ' }) // invalid
schema.validate({ a: '11' }) // invalid
```